# How read JSON nested from Angular JS $http service?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

This is my main JSON file

```
{
  "chartType" : ["column", "column", "pie"],
  "chartTitle": ["Cantidad de equipos", "Cantidad de artículos consumibles","Cantidad de empleados a cargo"],
  "yAxisTitle": ["Equipos", "Consumibles", "Empleados"],
  "seriesName": ["conexion_equipos_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_consumibles_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_basededatos_json.php"],
  "seriesData": ["conexion_equipos_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_consumibles_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_basededatos_json.php"]
}
```

That loads others PHP JSON_ENCODE files in "seriesName" and "seriesData".

These JSON results generate keys "id" and "nombre" (spanish word for name).

How read values for these keys through Angular Service $http.get of the main JSON?

****UPDATE (06/03/2016)****

I'm middle of road!

I read the JSON objects from "seriesName" array with angular.fromJson function as follow:

```
var deserialize = angular.FromJson(data);

var objects = deserialize.seriesName;

console.log(objects);
```

That's throws me an array of objects:

```
 ["conexion_equipos_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_consumibles_basededatos_json.php", "conexion_basededatos_json.php"]
```

Thus, how I could read the objects contained in these URL's through Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough have button, I could resolve this issue.

I have created a repository that integrates Angular.js, PHP, and Highcharts, with Materialize.css, adding series dynamically from external JSON.

link: https://github.com/Nullises/DynamicSeriesHighchartsAngular

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decode the JSON in PHP using `json_decode()`, then you treat the result as an object.

Try something like;

```
$data = xyz; // pass in the JSON object
$res = json_decode($data); // decode JSON
$chartType = $res->chartType; // access property as an object
```

You can also try `var_dump($res)` to get a clearer understanding of the structure and how to access it;

Comment: It is useful in PHP, but my question is related to Angular.JS... What would the aproximated function of json_decode for Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following.

```
$http.get('url_to_json').then(fucntion(response) {
  var myJson = response.data;
  var keys = Object.keys(myJson);
    console.log('Your keys', keys);
}, fucntion(error) {

});
```